# URL redirection to another page is happening,but login function not working

Tags: php, html, url, redirect

All,
I have a task where i'm trying to redirect URL from www.example.biz to www.example.com everything works fine except the login page where the post login pages not happening Particularly with the IE ,When i see the source of www.example.com the code below shows

```
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
<frame src="http://www.example.biz" frameborder="0" />
<frame frameborder="0" noresize />
</frameset>
```

I wanted to know where exactly framset is apllied to redirected pages.....

Comment: That is a terrible way to make two domains point to one.

Comment: Adding to this i doubt if there is any .htacces file for this domain .I also wanted to know that is there any option other than manupulation with the .htacces file

Comment: @alex i know that man .But i've been given the task of rectifying it. So i wanted the frames source .

Comment: I'm planning create one .htaccess file if the file doesn't  exist. bUt i think that may change  the few file permissions which i don't want to...

Answer (score 1):

Use htaccess for any such redirection. This will even help you in SEO.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old-domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I tried this option but browser redirecting to .com to biz but apparently redirection seems to be have gone to an infinite loop.So i'm not getting the pages...

Comment: Make sure your www.old-domain.com does not have anything similar.

Answer (score 0):

Well, my problem is solved .The problem was concerned with the enabling cookies for .biz domain  in the IE browser..